# Why is protected mode needed in addition to compatibility mode in Intel x86 64 bit CPUs?

Tags: x86, cpu, x86-64, protected-mode

I'm reading `intel` [software developer manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf) (section 3.1). Here is said that

> The IA-32 architecture supports three basic operating modes: protected
>   mode, real-address mode, and system management mode.

and

> Intel 64 architecture adds IA-32e mode. IA-32e mode has two sub-modes.

This two sub-modes is `Compatibility mode` and `64-bit mode`. Thus `Intel 64` architecture contains 4 operating modes (protected mode, real-address mode, system management mode, IA-32e mode). But I don't understand for what protected mode is needed in `Intel 64`? Compatibility sub-mode of IA-32e permit to run legacy 16- and 32-bits application without re-compilation to 64-bit OS and 64-bit sub-mode permits OS to run application which access to 64-bit linear address space. Where protected mode is used when I'm using 64-bit OS? Application running ensured by IA-32e mode.

Comment: It was a drop-in replacement for machines that boot an operating system that never heard of IA-32e mode.  Backwards compatibility is very important to get a new chip design to start selling quickly.

Comment: In fact, you lose one, the V8086 mode which is not supported in IA-32e mode. I suggest you review the x86 & Windows history, and then you'll get the answer.

Comment: Normally a 64-bit OS *doesn't* use protected-mode at all, after booting.  Pure protected mode is for 32-bit OSes.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the organization is like this. At any given time, the entire CPU must be in precisely one of the following modes (excluding the maintenance mode):

**IA-32 Real Mode:** This is how the processor powers on.

**IA-32 Protected Mode:** 32-bit execution environment. The usual protection mechanisms are in play; the CPU can selectively move into virtual-8086 mode.

**IA-32e Mode:** This is only available on 64-bit CPUs. The CPU can selectively move between compatibility and long mode.

That is, if you want to execute *any* 64-bit code, you need to go into IA-32e mode. You can now decide on a per-segment basis whether to execute 32-bit code in compatibility mode or 64-bit code in long mode.